# SharePoint Online Azure SQL Database External Content List Error

Tags: sharepoint-online, sql-server, external-content-type, azure, external-data

I have an Azure SQL database created.
I also have fallowed the steps listed here[External List from a SQL Azure table with Business Connectivity](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/make-an-external-list-from-a-sql-azure-table-with-business-connectivity-services-and-secure-store-466f3809-fde7-41f2-87f7-77d9fdadfc95#__toc350352766)

I have also created an external list on my SPO site. 
Everything from the Secure Store and BCS setting have worked with out a problem. I was able to set up the external content types inside of SharePoint Designer 2013, attaching the Azure SQL DB.

**My Problem**
I set up the external content list. the list page gets created, for a couple seconds I get a green ball on the screen as if its attempting to load the content into the frame. Then i get the error message:

> Unable to display this web part. to troubleshoot the problem open this web page in a Microsoft... 
>   With correlation ID: 6b4a7e9e-a4c-6000-0c42-df702e70a314

I could use some help with this. Please let me know if you have any questions about details.
Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Than you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot check the detail information based on Correlation ID in SharePoint Online like using in SharePoint On-premise, as Microsoft controls the back-end.

You need to new a service request in Office 365 admin center->Support to contact the backend engineers to check the information.